# Mojarra Java EE 5/6 compatibility

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, mojarra

Very simple question: is there anyone who has a link to "official" information on the Mojarra (JSF RI) compatibility with the Java EE 5 and 6 standards? I can't seem to find anything about this.

We're stuck with a Java EE 5 application server, and we'd like to know which version of Mojarra we can use. Currently, we're using 2.0.3 but this version suffers from a [nasty nested `ui:repeat`](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1807) bug. This has been solved in Mojarra 2.1.1, but there seems to be a lot of confusion about which Mojarra versions are still compatible with Java EE 5 (WebLogic 10.3.3 in our case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** *Thanks to Arjan Tijms for this clarifying comment:*

> Those notes are a bit confusing. Mojarra 2.1 can use Servlet 3.0, but
> does NOT require it. In fact, in some minor update accidentally a real
> dependency crept in and this was hastily reverted. Thus, **Mojarra 2.1.x
> indeed does run on Java EE 5**.

**Original answer:**

The official [Mojarra 2.1.1 release notes](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.1.1/releasenotes.html) state:

> This release of JSF requires:
>
> Java Servlet 3.0
>
> JavaServer TM Pages 2.1
>
> JavaServer TM Pages Standard
>
> Tag Library 1.2

And regarding [this (semi-official) source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history), Java EE 5 has only Java Servlet 2.5.

Comment: By applying the same logic, [version 2.0.9](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.0.9/releasenotes.html) is apparently the latest release that doesn't require Servlet 3.0. Thanks!

Comment: Those notes are a bit confusing. Mojarra 2.1 can *use* Servlet 3.0, but does NOT require it. In fact, in some minor update accidentally a real dependency crept in and this was hastily reverted. Thus, Mojarra 2.1.x indeed does run on Java EE 5.

Comment: @ArjanTijms Thanks Arjan. Hope you don't mind that I copied your comment into the answer since I think it is a useful addition.