# JSF 2.1.7 requirements

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jsf-2

does JSF 2.1.7 (and 2.1.x in general) require Servlet 3.0 or just 2.5?
If you look at pom http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/faces/jsf-api/2.1.7/jsf-api-2.1.7.pom you'll find servlet 3, but it seems referred to JSF 2.2 (see also tag name: "Oracle's implementation of the JSF 2.2 specification API.")

I've found different answers to this question on the web. Can anyone help me? Some links:

[Mojarra JSF 2.1.9 exception while loading a page which has got composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029472/mojarra-jsf-2-1-9-exception-while-loading-a-page-which-has-got-composite-compone)
[Mojarra Java EE 5/6 compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597568/mojarra-java-ee-5-6-compatibility/9597815#9597815)
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10140121

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-2_1-mrel2-eval-oth-JSpec/). Preface (Related technologies) says that one of requirements is Servlet API version 2.5, so you don't need version 3.0. Also this [page](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish-webtier/mojarra-jsf-21x-servlet-requirement-or-dependency-0) quotes Ed Burns who states that is dependent only on 2.5

Answer (score 3):

The Servlet 3.0 requirement in Mojarra 2.1 is merely for the "optional stuff", such as auto-registration of the `FacesServlet` on URL patterns `*.jsf`, `*.faces` and `/faces/*` without the need to write it down in webapp's own `web.xml`.

Mojarra 2.1 is however backwards compatible with Servlet 2.5, you'll only miss the "optional" stuff and among others need to register the `FacesServlet` in `web.xml` yourself (although I would personally [recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why/3008504#3008504) to do it anyway on an URL pattern of `*.xhtml`).